# Finding the pivot point for the given array. Java

Tags: java

[image: This is the question]**Question :-**
In the question we have to find the pivot index of the given array. And as per the given definition(given in the question) it is that point in the index such that if we calculate the sum of numbers on it's left and right they both comes out to be equal.

**Example**
Input: nums = [1,7,3,6,5,6]

Output: 3
Explanation:

The pivot index is 3.
Left sum = nums[0] + nums[1] + nums[2] = 1 + 7 + 3 = 11

Right sum = nums[4] + nums[5] = 5 + 6 = 11

**My Approach and logic I tried**

I calculate the total sum of array and then used a for loop to iterate from backwards in the array(from right to left) each time subtracting that element from total sum and comparing it to another loop which is calculating sum from right side such that when they get equal return that index element.

But I can't find the error

**Code for the same**

```
import java.util.*;
public class webs{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int arr[] = {1, 7, 3, 6, 5, 6};
        System.out.println(Calc(arr));
        
    }
    static int Calc(int arr[]){
        int sum = 0;
        int lsum = 0;
        //this loop is for sum
        for(int i =0; i < arr.length; i++){
            sum += arr[i];
        }
        //this loop is for calculating sum from reverse
        for(int j= arr.length - 1; j > 0; j--){
            lsum += arr[j];
            sum -= arr[j];

            if(lsum == sum){
                return arr[j];
            }
            else{
                return -1;
            }
        }
        return 0; 
    }
}
```

Please specify the error in this.

Comment: `return arr[j];`, that will return the value at that array index, but you want to return the value `j` instead, the actual array index.

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop, in method `Calc` will only execute, at most, one iteration since it contains an `if-else` where both the `if` returns a value and the `else` returns a value. If you run your code with a debugger, you will discover that.

When I copied your code to my Eclipse, it warned me that the `j--` part of the `for` loop is *dead code*. In other words it will never be executed because of the `if-else` statement in the loop body.

If `lsum` does not equal `sum` then you need to continue with the next loop iteration. Hence you need to remove the `else`.

Also, method `Calc` needs to return an index and not an element. Hence rather than

```java
return arr[j];
```

you should

```java
return j;
```

If the `for` loop terminates, that means that you did not find a pivot point and so the method should return -1 (negative one) and not zero. Hence the last line of method `Calc` should be

```java
return -1;
```

Also, since you are iterating the array backwards, `lsum` should initially contain the sum of all the array elements and `sum` should be zero. In fact you either need to reverse `sum` and `lsum` or iterate the array forwards instead of backwards.

When iterating the array backwards, the terminating condition should be

```java
j >= 0
```

and not

```java
j > 0
```

because then you don't iterate the first element in the array.

Lastly, you need to adjust the value of `sum` **after** you test whether `sum` equals `lsum`.

Here is my rewrite of your code, containing the changes that I have described, above. I added `print` statements so you can [partially] see what is happening but as I said before, you need to learn how to debug your code.

```java
static int Calc(int arr[]){
    int sum = 0;
    int lsum = 0;
    //this loop is for sum
    for(int i =0; i < arr.length; i++){
        lsum += arr[i];
    }
    //this loop is for calculating sum from reverse
    for(int j= arr.length - 1; j >= 0; j--){
        lsum -= arr[j];
        System.out.printf("%d. lsum = %d , sum = %d%n", j, lsum, sum);
        if(lsum == sum){
            System.out.println("Returning: " + j);
            return j;
        }
        sum += arr[j];
    }
    System.out.println("Returning: -1");
    return -1; 
}
```

When I call method `Calc` with the sample array from your question, the following is printed:

```
5. lsum = 22 , sum = 0
4. lsum = 17 , sum = 6
3. lsum = 11 , sum = 11
Returning: 3
```